# Serializing Rails 6 models based on current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an API controller, I'd like to limit what fields of a model can be seen depending on who is logged in. ActiveModel Serializers would seem to allow this, but I've had no luck with the following:

```
class MyModelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :custom_field, :secret_field

  has_many :linked_records

  def custom_field
    object.do_something
  end

  def filter(keys)
    unless scope.is_admin?
      keys.delete :secret_field
      keys.delete :linked_records
    end
    keys
  end
end
```

But, the filtering is never performed and so my output always contains :secret_field and :linked_records even if there's no user logged in.

Perhaps this is because I am using Rails 6, and it would seem that ActiveModel Serializers might no longer be the best tool (e.g. https://stevenyue.com/blogs/migrating-active-model-serializers-to-jserializer).

Please do offer your suggestions for a means to perform this, if you can think of a better means.

EDIT:

Further to all the comments below, here's some different code:

```
  attributes :name, :id, :admin_only_field, :is_admin

  $admin_only = %i[:id, :admin_only_field]

  def attributes(*args)
    hash = super
    $admin_only.each do |key|
      unless scope.is_admin?
        hash.delete(key)
      end
    end
    hash
  end

  def is_admin
    if scope.is_admin?
      'admin!'
    else
      'not an admin!'
    end
  end
```

If I then visit the model's index page without being an admin I see that the admin_only_field and id are both present, and is_admin says that I'm not. Bizarre.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705802/conditional-attributes-in-active-model-serializers

Comment: Nothing so far, though I have still to try the last method mentioned (Passalini).

Comment: Hmm... The `scope.is_admin?` is really suspicious. Are you able to debug and confirm that the code inside `unless` is reached?

Comment: I've tried various debugging steps. The is_admin code test works as expected but the hash.delete does not actually delete anything, it would seem.

Comment: What is your Ruby version?

Comment: I just tested with Ruby-2.7.0 and Rails-6.0.2.1. Both of the ***inline condition*** and the ***attributes overriding*** are working for me. :(

Comment: I'm using Ruby-2.6.5 and Rails-6.0.2.1. I'd be surprised if it's the ruby version which is responsible, but I suppose I'll have to try that.

Comment: This is utterly perplexing so I have added some further information in the original post.

Comment: ***If I then visit the model's index page without being an admin I see that the admin_only_field and id are both present, and is_admin says that I'm not.*** Definitely the  `scope.is_admin?` is `false` here

Comment: The admin detection is definitely working correctly, so the failure to delete from the hash is perplexing. Anyway, this morning I have tried again with code similar to that above and seem to have had some success, so what has caused the issue remains unclear.

Comment: Glad to hear this issue is resolved, but it is better to understand why though.

Comment: Indeed - I would very much like to know. I suppose I will have to keep working on it to see if any clues appear.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class MyModelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :custom_field, :secret_field

  has_many :linked_records

  def custom_field
    object.do_something
  end

 private

  def attributes
    hash = super
    unless scope.is_admin?
      hash.delete :secret_field
      hash.delete :linked_records
    end
    hash
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That code gives me: `private method 'attributes' called for #<MyModelSerializer:0x00007fabdf34fcf0> Did you mean? attributes_hash`; if I don't have the method as private I get an argument error:: `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) `.